# How to change a single letter in input string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie in Python so that I have a question. I want to change letter in word  if the first letter appears more than once. Moreover I want to use input to get the word from user. I'll present the problem using an example:

```
word = 'restart'
```

After changes the word should be like this:

```
word = 'resta$t'
```

I was trying couple of ideas but always I got stuck. Is there any simple sollutions for this?
Thanks in advance.

### EDIT: In response to Simas Joneliunas

It's not my homework. I'm just finished reading some basic Python tutorials and I found  some questions that I couldn't solve on my own. My first thought was to separate word into a single letters and then to find out the place of the letter I want to replace by "$". I have wrote that code but I couldn't came up with sollution how to get to specific place and replace it.

```
word = 'restart'
how_many = {}
for x in word:
    how_many=+1
else:
    how_many=1
for y in how_many:
    if how_many[y] > 0:
      print(y,how_many[y])
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment (because of the user input requirement). Can you show us some of your code? What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I did edit my post

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.replace`:

```
s = "restart"
new_s = s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], "$")
```

Output:

```
'resta$t'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"".join([["$" if ch in word[:i] else ch for i, ch in enumerate(word)])
```

- `enumerate` iterates through the string (i.e. a list of characters) and keeps a running index of the iteration
- `word[:i]` checks the list of chars until the current index, i.e. previously appeared characters
- `"$" if ch in word[:i] else ch` means replace the character at existing position with $ if it appears before others keep the character
- `"".join()` joins the list of characters into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the python console is handy and lets you experiment.  Since you have to keep track of number of letters, for a good visual I would list the alphabet in a list. Then in the loop remove from the list the current letter. If letter does not exist in the list replace the letter with $.
So check if it exists first thing in the loop, if it exists, remove it, if it doesn’t exist replace it from example above.